# how to calculate precision recall, ROC, and f1 score for negative classes?

Tags: roc, precision-recall

I want to calculate performance metrics such as precision-recall and f1 scores with respect to the negative class, aka I want to calculate the propotion of correctly labeled negatives out of all the negative elements, etc.

How would I do this? If I already had a list of probabilities (prediction is 1 if probability were greater than some threshold, 0 otherwise) and values (i.e. 1 if true, 0 if false), would I just take 1-probability and 1-value and then compute the precision recall?

My data looks like this:

```
Probability (calculated from xgboost) | True Value
.3 | 0
.7 | 1
.6 | 0
.5 | 1
.1 | 0
.2 | 0
.9 | 1
...
```

etc.

Comment: You tagged this question with ROC, are you interested in that too? I'm asking because the answer might be rather different...

Comment: Yes yes, that too.

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. These measures take into account both positive and the negative class. There is no "with regard to the class" possible. "I want to calculate the proportion of correctly labeled negatives out of all the negative elements" is something that can be answered though.

Comment: But please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and be specific. You need to show us what you've done so far. How is the data stored? Etc.

Comment: Updated to show how the data looks.